# How to save the iteration values of a loop in a vector in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, vector

I am trying to generate random numbers using the metropolis algorithm, but I can't get it to work because it is not saving the 100,000 samples that I need. How do I get it to save the samples in c()?

Here is what I have:

```
funct <- function(x) { dnorm(x,-2,1) * 1/3 + dnorm(x,2,1) * 2/3 }

samples <- c()
x = 0
random_walk_std = 1
delta = rnorm( 1, mean = 0, sd = 1 ) 

while( length(samples) < 100000)
{
  xp = x + delta
  r = funct(xp)/funct(x)

  if( r>=1 ){

    x <- xp
    samples 

    samples =samples + 1
  }

  else if (r<=1){

    s = runif(1, min=0, max=1)

    if( s<=r ){

      x <- xp
      x[samples] = samples + 1

       samples[x] =samples + 1
    }
   }
  end
}

hist( samples, probability=TRUE, col=gray(.9), lwd=2, main="" )
curve( funct(x), add=T, lwd=2)
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: Something like `samples <- c(samples, newvalue)` should do

Comment: when you know the size of the result you want, initialize your variable to be that size, `samples <- numeric(100000)`.  Something this simple can increase the speed of your code by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

With some code editing, please check this result versus your expected output:

```
set.seed(111)
while( length(samples) < 100)
{
  xp = x + delta
  r = funct(xp)/funct(x)

  if( r>=1 ){

    x <- xp
    samples <- c(samples, x) 
  }

  else if (r<=1){

    s = runif(1, min=0, max=1)

    if( s<=r ){

      x <- xp
      samples <- c(samples, x)
    }
   }
}


samples
#   [1]  0.2083592  0.4167183  0.6250775  0.8334367  1.0417958  1.2501550  1.4585142
#   [8]  1.6668733  1.8752325  2.0835917  2.2919508  2.5003100  2.7086692  2.9170283
#  [15]  3.1253875  3.3337467  3.5421058  3.7504650  3.9588242  4.1671833  4.3755425
```

Your code has a few control flow inconsistencies. You check `if( r>=1 )` then you check `if (r<=1)`, you should specify which condition you'd like 1 to fall under. Also at the end you check `if( s<=r )`, what should happen if `s > r`? Was this intentional? For now it is ignored until another statement is added.

Comment: Well, `1` is not excluded, rather repeatedly included. `s` cannot be greater than `r` within the `if (r<=1)` bit; they're just randomly deciding whether to keep or drop that round of `samples`, with `r` being the probability of keeping, I think.

Comment: Another minor point: since `x` is a scalar at all times, we know that `samples` will end up being length `100`. We could generate an empty `samples` at the start and fill it `samples[i] <- x`, where `i` is some iterator that increments just before that line.

Comment: The issue with 1 is that there are two instructions for when r=1. For now the first condition call will be used but the user should verify that it is in fact the correct behavior.

Comment: Sure, I was just saying "excluded" isn't the right word. Your answer is good, but I fear we're getting into code review territory here (since the OP's loop has even more serious flaws).